# Customer care accelerator integration with CRM, Online showing error

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, dynamics-crm-2011

I have a task of connecting customer care accelerator to a Crm online following these steps

http://garethtuckercrm.com/2011/07/14/installing-the-customer-care-accelerator-cca-for-crm-2011/

CCA get connected to on premise  but while connecting to online, it showing an error.

as

```
unable to retrieve organization from discovery device
```

and exception it showing

```
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.ProcessReply(Message reply, SecurityProtocolCorrelationState correlationState, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SecurityChannelFactory`1.SecurityRequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.IWSTrustContract.Issue(Message message)
   at Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.WSTrust.WSTrustChannel.Issue(RequestSecurityToken rst, RequestSecurityTokenResponse& rstr)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateLiveIdInternal(ClientCredentials clientCredentials, SecurityTokenResponse deviceToken, String keyType)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceConfiguration`1.AuthenticateDevice(ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.DiscoveryServiceConfiguration.AuthenticateDevice(ClientCredentials clientCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.AuthenticateDeviceCore()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.AuthenticateCore()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.Authenticate()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceProxy`1.ValidateAuthentication()
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ServiceContextInitializer`1.Initialize(ServiceProxy`1 proxy)
   at Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.DiscoveryServiceProxy.Execute(DiscoveryRequest request)
   at Microsoft.Uii.AifServices.AuthenticationService.DiscoverOrganizations(Uri discoveryServiceUri, Uri homeRealmUri, ClientCredentials clientCredentials, ClientCredentials deviceCredentials)
   at Microsoft.Uii.CrmConnection.CrmConnection.RetrieveOrganizations()
   at Microsoft.Uii.CrmConnection.ConnectionsForm.OpenConnection(CrmConnection con)
Inner Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException: Authentication Failure
```

If anyone have face integrating the customer care accelerator with crm specified above error. Do share there research

Answer (score 0):

What is the OrganizationService URL you are using in the config file?
Verify that it is the same as the URL from the following section in CRM Online

Settings->Customization->Developer Resources-> Organization Service

Also, make sure that authenticationMode is "Online".

Comment: sir basically while basically after running the riconfigloader application. C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Uii\CCA\Source Code\RIConfigLoader\RIConfigLoader\bin\Debug.. and trying connecting to Crm though Discovery service.It shows the above exception

Comment: https://da5t.api.crm5.dynamics.com/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc this url i am using in my config file.

Comment: You mentioned that you were trying to connect to online. That does not look like an online URL.

Comment: there were some Dll problem. it runs after changing those dll. Thanks